# Spring MVC controller works 2 times on 1 click

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pagination

I`m trying make a pagination using Spring MVC. My controller recieves 2 parameters by ajax:
- how many elements per page to show (rows)
- which page is selected

```
@Controller
public class SymptomController {

@Autowired
private SymptomService symptomService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/symptoms", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String symptomPage(
    @RequestParam(required = false, value = "rows") Integer rows,
    @RequestParam(required = false, value = "page") Integer tabNumber,
    Model model) {
Page<Symptom> page = null;
if ((rows == null) && (tabNumber == null)) {
    page = symptomService.findSymptomsByPage(0, 10);
    System.out.println(1);
} else {
    page = symptomService.findSymptomsByPage(tabNumber - 1, rows);
    System.out.println(rows + "  " + tabNumber);
}
int currentPage = page.getNumber() + 1;
int first = Math.max(1, currentPage - 3);
int last = Math.min(currentPage + 2, page.getTotalPages());

model.addAttribute("symptom", new Symptom());
model.addAttribute("symptomPage", page);
model.addAttribute("currentPage", currentPage);
model.addAttribute("first", first);
model.addAttribute("last", last);
return "symptoms";
}
```

My jsp:

```
<table id="table-methods-table"
        class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: #F5F5F5">
                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="false" data-align="center"></th>
                <th data-field="editBtn" data-align="center"><spring:message
                        code="label.editsymptom" /></th>
                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true" data-align="left"><spring:message
                        code="label.symptoms" /></th>
                <th data-field="description" data-sortable="true" data-align="left"><spring:message
                        code="label.descpiption" /></th>
                <!--<th data-field="operate" data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents">Delete</th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
            <c:forEach items="${symptomPage.content}" var="symptom">
                <tr>
                    <td class="bs-checkbox"><input name="SelectItem"
                        type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td><a href="#edit" data-toggle="modal"> <i
                            class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></td>
                    <td>${symptom.name}</td>
                    <td><i>${symptom.description}</i></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<ul class="pagination no-margin pull-right">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${currentPage == 1}">
            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <li><a href="${firstURL}">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="${prevURL}">&lt;</a></li>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="${first}" end="${last}">
        <c:url var="pageUrl" value="/symptoms" />
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${i == currentPage}">
                <li class="active"><a href="${pageUrl}"><c:out value="${i}"></c:out></a></li>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <li><a href="${pageUrl}"><c:out value="${i}"></c:out></a></li>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${currentPage != last}">
            <li><a href="${nextURL}">&gt;</a></li>
            <li><a href="${lastURL}">&raquo;</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</ul>
<select id="select" class="form-control"
    style="width: 80px; margin-top: 18px;">
    <option selected="selected">10</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>100</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var pads = $('ul.pagination').children();
    pads.click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : "/hospital/symptoms",
            data: {rows: parseInt($('#select').text()), page: parseInt($(this).text())},
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the page buttons I recieve that on my console:

```
    Hibernate: select count(symptom0_.id) as col_0_0_ from symptoms symptom0_
Hibernate: select symptom0_.id as id16_, symptom0_.symptom_description as symptom2_16_, symptom0_.symptom_name as symptom3_16_ from symptoms symptom0_ limit ?, ?
10  3
Hibernate: select count(symptom0_.id) as col_0_0_ from symptoms symptom0_
Hibernate: select symptom0_.id as id16_, symptom0_.symptom_description as symptom2_16_, symptom0_.symptom_name as symptom3_16_ from symptoms symptom0_ limit ?
1
Hibernate: select count(symptom0_.id) as col_0_0_ from symptoms symptom0_
Hibernate: select symptom0_.id as id16_, symptom0_.symptom_description as symptom2_16_, symptom0_.symptom_name as symptom3_16_ from symptoms symptom0_ limit ?, ?
10  2
Hibernate: select count(symptom0_.id) as col_0_0_ from symptoms symptom0_
Hibernate: select symptom0_.id as id16_, symptom0_.symptom_description as symptom2_16_, symptom0_.symptom_name as symptom3_16_ from symptoms symptom0_ limit ?
1
```

That explaines that controller works 2 times on 1 click. Please, advice me what I have to do to make controller work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the browser is sending twice the same request:

- once with the javascript code you worte
- once with the native click event on the `<a>` link itself

You may need to [prevent the default browser action with jquery](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var pads = $('ul.pagination').children();
    pads.click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : "/hospital/symptoms",
            data: {rows: parseInt($('#select').text()), page: parseInt($(this).text())},
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I resolved this issue by using .on function on the parrent tag, giving as arrguments 'click', 'li>span', function() {}. It works nice now. But I thank you for your answer. I`ll try this approach also.